# How to animate a button? (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, button, translation

I'm new at Xcode and Objectice C and would preciate some help with my app. I want to add a translation animation to a button. What would be the code to, for example, move "button" from X:30 Y:50 to X:10 Y:70? Thanks :).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For old compilers/iOSes:

```
// set the original frame
button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 100);

// animate to the new one
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

For newer compilers/iOSes:

```
// set the original frame
button.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 100, 100);

// animate
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    button.frame = CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100);
}];
```

Comment: @Fernando this would be the better option

Comment: @Jeeter I kindly ask you to remove your answer, it's really a bad idea to do.

Comment: all right, I deleted it. Do you know of anywhere where I could learn more about this?

Comment: @Jeeter my best source always stays developer.apple.com. Specifically, look for UIKit framework reference. Also give CoreAnimation and CoreGraphics a go.

Comment: Good answer @H2CO3, I had no idea that they added the new method to doing an animation, what iOS version did that start in?

Answer (score 0):

UIView (a super class of UIButton) has the ability to be animated, use something like the following.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-20, 20);
[aButton setTransform:transform];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Also note that context need not be an object as it's declared as void *. It should be NULL.